# Saving Listview State before replacing the fragment

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragments

I have a Custom list inside a fragment. Then I replace the fragment with another list.

I want when I come back to my former list (which was destroyed as the result of replacing fragment) restore the last state of the list (like checked items or spinner selected items).
I know that I must use `onSaveInstanteState` and put the last state of the list into that then get them from `onActivityCreated` bundle. The problem is that my list is complex and has a bean class and CustomAdapter. I think I can use the code below:

(I used `private List<NameBean> items;`):

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        // Retrive Data from list
        for (NameBean bean : items) {
            /* bean gets the orders values from NamesAdapters and MainActivity.
        But the orders like "isSelected" (value of a boolean which is defined here in upper block) or
        "IsSelected" and "SetSelected" which gets and sets the value of the boolean "selected" in 
        NameBean.java (Setters and getters) in conditional (boolean) format (true or false).
        We can access them in MainActivity and NamesAdapter   */
            if (bean.isSelected()) {
                sb.append(bean.getName() + ": " + bean.getSpinnerItem());
                sb.append("\n");
            }
        }
        showAlertView(sb.toString().trim());
    }
```

My NameBean class is as below:

```
public class NameBean {

private String name;
private String spinnerItem;
private SpinnerAdapter spinnerAdapter;
private boolean selected;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public boolean isSelected() {
    return selected;
}

public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
    this.selected = selected;
}

public SpinnerAdapter getSpinnerAdapter() {
    return spinnerAdapter;
}

public void setSpinnerAdapter(SpinnerAdapter spinnerAdapter) {
    this.spinnerAdapter = spinnerAdapter;
}

public String getSpinnerItem() {
    return spinnerItem;
}

public void setSpinnerItem(String spinnerItem) {
    this.spinnerItem = spinnerItem;
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer easy and tricky!

There is no reason (in my case) for saving the complex list before replacing the fragments.
I just defined the fragments dynamically and set tag to the fragments. Then instead of replacing them, hide one and show the other. This code is in main Activity:

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    WebViewerFragment firstfragment = new WebViewerFragment();
    WebViewerFragment_II secondfragment = new WebViewerFragment_II();
    fm.beginTransaction()
    .add(R.id.detail_fragment, firstfragment, "1")
    .add(R.id.detail_fragment, secondfragment, "2")
    .hide(secondfragment)
    .addToBackStack(null)
    .commit();
```

(I was forced to add the second fragment cause this is the only way to add tag to the fragment dynamically! and I need this tag for responding to actions for changing the fragments). Then I change the fragment content by toggling their visibility:

```
FragmentManager fms = getFragmentManager();
        Fragment firstFragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("1");
        Fragment secondFragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("2");
        fms.beginTransaction()
        .hide(secondFragment)
        .show(firstFragment)
        .addToBackStack(null)
        .commit();
```

I hope I could help someone having this problem cause it approximately made me crazy. This is obvious that whenever you want, you can handle them (f.e. for obtaining the default view) by transaction operation like replace or remove (multiple fragments) and adding `.commit();` at the end of transaction will take action for all changes simultaneously.